# Why is matcher.group giving me an error?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, compilation

I am trying to compile the following while loop, but I keep getting a red flag in eclipse next to the group.matcher("...") that says to remove the argument so i match group.

The error i am getting is the following:

The method group(int) in the type Matcher is not applicable for the arguments (String)

The method group(int) in the type Matcher is not applicable for the arguments (String)

The method group(int) in the type Matcher is not applicable for the arguments (String)

The method group(int) in the type Matcher is not applicable for the arguments (String)

The method group(int) in the type Matcher is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Here is the code:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group(TokenType.NUMBER.name()) != null) {
            tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.NUMBER, matcher.group(TokenType.NUMBER.name())));
            continue;
        } else if (matcher.group(TokenType.BINARYOP.name()) != null) {
            tokens.add(new Token(TokenType.BINARYOP, matcher.group(TokenType.BINARYOP.name())));
            continue;
        } else if (matcher.group(TokenType.WHITESPACE.name()) != null)
            continue;
    }
```

Comment: As error explain, group method require a int, and you pass it a String.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I assume that you use Java 6 or below, `matcher.group` takes only a int as parameter. If you want to use `matcher.group(String)` upgrade your project to Java 7. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(java.lang.String)
and
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group(java.lang.String)

Comment: But i am using eclipse, and as far as i researched it uses java 7 by default

Comment: @Predator44 It probably uses whatever you have. Check the menu `Project>Properties`. The build path tab includes the JRE library used, and the Java Compiler tab, the compliance level. What do they show?

Comment: In Eclipse, go to Window, Preferences, Java, Compiler and see what's in compiler compliance level.

Comment: You are definitely right, it uses java 6, although i have java 8 installed on my mac, but i can't seem to find the package to select it

Comment: That's probably the difference between JRE and JDK. you probably have Java JRE 8 and a Java JDK 6

Comment: @JFPicard Project>Properties. The build path tab includes the JRE library used java se 1.6. Although i followed your recommendation and installed the JDK 8, but it does not appear in the window

Comment: @JFPicardI figured it out ! i had to create a new project. Thank your for your help